# Could someone provide pseudocode for this please?

Tags: c++

I am not a C++ programmer, but this algorithm appeared in an operating manual for a machine I'm using and I'm struggling to make sense of it. I'd like someone to explain some terms within it, or possibly the flow of the entire code, given that I don't have time to learn C in the course of the project.

Waveform files for the machine in question are made up of a number of tags in curly brackets. The checksum is calculated using the WAVEFORM tag, {WAVEFORM-length: #data}.

The "data" consists of a number of bytes represented as hexadecimal numbers. "length" is the number of bytes in the "data", while "start" apparently points to the first byte in the "data".

I've managed to work out some of the terms, but I'm particularly unsure about my interpretation of `((UINT32 *)start)[i]`

```
UINT32 checksum(void *start, UINT32 length)
{
    UINT32 i, result = 0xA50F74FF;
    for(i=0; i < length/4; i++)
        result = result ^ ((UINT32 *)start)[i];
    return(result);
}
```

So from what I can tell, the code does the following:

1. Take the address of the first byte in the "data" and the length of the "data"
2. Create a variable called result, which is an unsigned integer `A50F74FF`
3. For each byte in the first 25% of the data string, raise "result" to that power (presumably modulo 2^32)
4. Return result as the value `checksum`

Am I correct here or have I misread the algorithm on one of the steps? I feel like I can't be correct, because basing a checksum on only part of the data wouldn't spot errors in the later parts of the data.

Comment: And you should probably [get a couple of good books too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282). The operator `^` is not a power or "raise" operator, it's the bitwise [exclusice or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operation.

Comment: `^` is not *raise to the power*, it's a bitwise exclusive-or. Otherwise you're more or less correct.

Comment: You are simply XORing `result` with each *double-word* (32-bits) in `start` and then returning `result`.

Comment: Also note that the function is prone to *undefined behavior* because it could possibly break [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). And it requires the length to be a multiple of 4, otherwise it will not use all the bytes for the checksum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the pseudocode for this function is roughly like this:

```
function checksum(DATA)
    RESULT = 0xA50F74FF;
    for each DWORD in DATA do
        RESULT = RESULT xor DWORD
    return RESULT
```

where `DWORD` is a four-byte integer value.

The function is actually going though (almost) all of the data (not 25%) but it's doing it in 4-byte increments that's why the `length` which is in bytes is divided by 4.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's not quite clear to me, from the original code, why start[0] is the beginning, but start[1] is the fifth byte. Is it that the UINT32 tells it that each address must be 32 bits long, or is there some other reason?

Comment: @Patrick, `(UINT32 *)` is telling the compiler to interpret `start` as a pointer to 4-byte integer and since pointers in C can be used as arrays each `((UINT32 *)start)[i]` is i-th 4-byte element in an array that starts at `start`.

Answer (score 3):

> 3. For each byte in the first 25% of the data string, raise "result" to that power (presumably modulo 2^32)

This is wrong. `^` is the bitwise XOR operation. It does not raise to a power.

Also, about *"of the data string"*. The algorithm iterates the pointed data as if it is an array of `UINT32`. In fact, if `start` doesn't point to (an element of) an array of `UINT32`, then the behaviour of the program is undefined<sup>1</sup>. It would be much better to declare the argument to be `UINT32*` in the first place, and not use the explicit cast.

Also, about *"For each byte in the first 25% of the data string"*, the algorithm appears to go through (nearly<sup>2</sup>) all bytes from `start` to `start + length`. `length` is presumably measured in bytes, and `UINT32` is presumably a type that consists of 4 bytes. Thus an array of `UINT32` objects of `N` bytes contains `N/4` elements `UINT32` of objects. Note that this assumes that the byte is 8 bits wide which is probably an assumption that the manual can make, but keep in mind that it is not an assumption portable to all systems.

<sup>1</sup> UB as far as the C++ language is concerned. But, if it's shown in the operating manual of a machine, then perhaps the special compiler for the particular hardware specifies defined behaviour for this. That said, it is also quite possible for the author of the manual to have made a mistake.

<sup>2</sup> If length is not divisible by 4, then the remaining 1-3 bytes are not used.